tbl_svysummary() outputs in R
How do I get the mean and se for the categorical variable in tbl_svysummary? I can only get percentage and p.std.error (percentage standard error). Is there a way to get results via svytotal instead of svymean?
library(survey)
library(gtsummary)

data(api, package = "survey") 
svyex2 <- svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc)

tbl_svysummary(svyex2, by = "both", include = c(api00, stype))


Does it make sense to calculate the mean of a categorical variable?
